# Rails bundle install path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use the path flag for bundle install, why does the Ruby version go to 2.1.0 when I am using version 2.1.5?

For example:

```
bundle install --path ~/bundled
```

Set the structure to:

```
ls ~/bundled/ruby/2.1.0/
bin/            build_info/     bundler/        cache/          doc/            extensions/     gems/           specifications/
```

Why is it 2.1.0 instead of 2.1.5?

Answer (score 2):

`2.1.0` in the library path refers to the *Ruby library version*, which is not necessarily identical to your Ruby version.

All 2.1.x versions of Ruby can safely share the same gems, which is why when you `bundle install` gems using Ruby 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, and 2.1.4, they all put the gems in the same `2.1.0` directory.

Comment: That seems kind of silly.  If that is the case, wouldn't a 2.1 or 2.1.x name be better?   I guess now I know and that's one to grow on!